# IndexedDB fcm_token_details_db version has changed from '1' to '3'

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am getting the following console error:

`Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The requested version (1) is less than the existing version (3).`

Looking through the all IndexedDB options for my domain in Chrome developer tools > 'Application' (tab) > 'Storage' selection (in sidebar) > 'IndexedDB' (dropdown):

The only selection that I see with a version 3 is the `fcm_token_details_db` option.

Has something changed? Is this a bug? It seems to me that there's no way for me to explicitly declare the version for this, that it's declared in the FCM messaging library.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was from running 2 different versions of the FCM scripts in different places. In one file we had:

`importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.6.2/firebase-app.js')
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.6.2/firebase-messaging.js')`

and in another area we had:

`importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.4.1/firebase-app.js')
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.4.1/firebase-messaging.js')`

Somewhere between the above mentioned script versions, Firebase made updates to the Indexedb version number.

There doesn't seem to be mention of this in the release docs.

https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js